# Seeking birth family of Srinivasan with parents Arunasalam and Amirtham poondi thanjavur in India?

Tags: 20th-century, birth-records, india

I am a 1st generation Indian breed born in Malaysia. My father Indian born sometime in 1913 - 1915 left Thanjavur, India when he was in his teen. His name is Srinivasan. He has passed on in the year 2000
at the age of 87 years old. I am looking to reconnect with the other
family members of his siblings family. My father's younger brother name Thanduyapani / Dhandabani
and younger sister Vijaya Lakshmi. He probably has other older siblings.

His late father's name : Arunasalam / Arunachalam
His late mother's name : Amirtham

Both of them born sometime in the 1870s onwards.

His siblings probably would have passed on.

The only clue , I have is he is  kallar poondi vandayar
I am looking for his village. Probably in the area of Orthanadu, Tanjavur, India.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to. Have you found your father in each census that he is likely to have participated in to determine whether any siblings may be with him?